# Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Permission denied when inplementing codecoverage (SonarQube) in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, .net-core, sonarqube, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I try to implement codecoverage results in SonarQube trough the Azure DevOps Pipeline(for a dotnetcore application), I followed the steps in: https://mohitgoyal.co/2018/10/11/configure-code-coverage-for-dotnet-core-2-0-based-applications-using-sonarqube-and-azure-devops/

After trying to run the build pipeline I encounter a error:

```
2018-11-30T09:54:24.2926108Z Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Permission denied
2018-11-30T09:54:24.2990180Z    at Interop.Sys.ForkAndExecProcess(String filename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean redirectStdin, Boolean redirectStdout, Boolean redirectStderr, Boolean setUser, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, Int32& lpChildPid, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean shouldThrow)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3011246Z    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3030150Z    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3088324Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.PlatformAbstractions.ProcessHelper.LaunchProcess(String processPath, String arguments, String workingDirectory, IDictionary`2 envVariables, Action`2 errorCallback, Action`1 exitCallBack)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3108677Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.DataCollection.DefaultDataCollectionLauncher.LaunchDataCollector(IDictionary`2 environmentVariables, IList`1 commandLineArguments)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3128897Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.DataCollection.ProxyDataCollectionManager.Initialize()
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3186941Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.ProxyExecutionManagerWithDataCollection.Initialize(Boolean skipDefaultAdapters)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3208296Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.Parallel.ParallelProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRunOnConcurrentManager(IProxyExecutionManager proxyExecutionManager)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3228197Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.Parallel.ParallelProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRunPrivate(ITestRunEventsHandler runEventsHandler)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3304345Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CrossPlatEngine.Client.Parallel.ParallelProxyExecutionManager.StartTestRun(TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsHandler eventHandler)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3326651Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Client.Execution.TestRunRequest.ExecuteAsync()
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3385754Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.TestPlatformHelpers.TestRequestManager.RunTests(IRequestData requestData, TestRunCriteria testRunCriteria, ITestRunEventsRegistrar testRunEventsRegistrar, TestPlatformOptions options)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3410931Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.TestPlatformHelpers.TestRequestManager.RunTests(TestRunRequestPayload testRunRequestPayload, ITestHostLauncher testHostLauncher, ITestRunEventsRegistrar testRunEventsRegistrar, ProtocolConfig protocolConfig)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3469455Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Processors.RunTestsArgumentExecutor.RunTests(IEnumerable`1 sources)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3489375Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Processors.RunTestsArgumentExecutor.Execute()
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3508726Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Executor.ExecuteArgumentProcessor(IArgumentProcessor processor, Int32& exitCode)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3567237Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Executor.Execute(String[] args)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.3586900Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.CommandLine.Program.Main(String[] args)
2018-11-30T09:54:24.8030948Z ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/dotnet failed with return code: 1
2018-11-30T09:54:24.8228558Z ##[error]Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects : /vsts/agent/_work/1/s/src/Services/HELLOAPI/10 Business/HELLO.Business.Test/HELLO.Business.Test.csproj
2018-11-30T09:54:24.8457211Z ##[section]Finishing: dotnet test
```

I think i've done something wrong in the dotnet Test step:
[image]

Comment: Did you verify that you can run the test task without codecoverage enabled?

Comment: @RobBos yes, I can run the test without codecoverage enabled